# Completeness results for quantified tense logics with BF?

Tags: lo.logic, modal-logic

Modal tense logics or temporal logics are important in that they correspond with partial orders and their extensions.

Are there completeness results for quantified temporal logics with the Barcan formula? A survey of results would be most welcome.